Animating a Polygonal Chain Worm's Gait
Here is an example polygonal chain worm:

that was created with the code:
polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]Height=RandomReal[{.5,2}];
polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]Period=RandomReal[{0,.25}];
polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]SegmentQuantity=RandomInteger[{1,20}];
polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]StartingX=RandomReal[{-5,-10}];
Plot[
Abs[TriangleWave[{polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]StartingX,-1*polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]StartingX},polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]Period*x]],
{x, 0, 1/(4*polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]Period)*polygonalChainWorm\[LetterSpace]SegmentQuantity},
AspectRatio->Automatic,Axes->False,ImageSize->Large,PlotStyle->{Black,Thickness[.01]}
]

and like all worms, it is hungry for an apple:

but so far all I have this:

using the code:
\[Gamma]=RandomReal[{0,Pi/4}];
\[ScriptL]=RandomReal[{0,4*Pi}];
a=\[ScriptL];
b=\[ScriptL];
c=Sqrt[a^2-2*a*b*Cos[\[Gamma]]+b^2];
Subscript[p,1]={-c/2,0};
Subscript[p,2]={c/2,0};
Subscript[p,3]={0,Sqrt[\[ScriptL]^2-Abs[c/2]^2]};
ListLinePlot[{Subscript[p,1],Subscript[p,3],Subscript[p,2]},AspectRatio->Automatic,Axes->False];
angleList=Table[\[Gamma]+i,{i,0,(Pi-\[Gamma]),(Pi-\[Gamma])/20}];
slides=Table[
\[Nu]\[Gamma]=angleList[[i]];
\[Nu]c=Sqrt[a^2-2*a*b*Cos[\[Nu]\[Gamma]]+b^2];
Subscript[p,1]={c/2-\[Nu]c,0};
Subscript[p,2]={c/2,0};
Subscript[p,3]={(c-\[Nu]c)/2,Sqrt[\[ScriptL]^2-Abs[(\[Nu]c-c)/2]^2]};
ListLinePlot[{Subscript[p,1],Subscript[p,3],Subscript[p,2]},AspectRatio->Automatic,Axes->True],
{i,1,Length[angleList]}];
ListAnimate[slides,Length[slides]]

which can be verified by:
EuclideanDistance[Subscript[p,1],Subscript[p,3]]==EuclideanDistance[Subscript[p,2],Subscript[p,3]]

since we applied the basic trigonometric formulas:

but the code is already complicated and prone to make mistakes when adding steps.And possibly solving unsolvable equations.  So, I am curious how I can use Mathematica to make it more readable to animate this.
I think that the steps the polygonal chain worm would take, supposing that the apple is horizontally left of the polygonal chain worm, are as follows:

First two segments moves to the left by flattening with only the left two points moving to the left.
If that is not enough, then the third and fourth move by 'scrunching'.
The wave carries along until the original shape is formed but to the left.
Steps 1-3 are repeated until the apple is reached.


Here is a quick and dirty code that should get you going.
"ext" extends the worm to the left and "contr" contracts its tail.
ext[i0_, worm0_, target_] := 
  Module[{worm = worm0, dx = 1/10, i1 = i0, i2 = i0 + 1},
   If[EvenQ[i0] || i0 >= Length[worm], 
    Print["i1 must be odd or smaller than length:", i1]; Return[]];
   Reap[
     While[
      target < worm[[1, 1]] && (worm[[i2, 1]] - worm[[i1, 1]] + dx) <=
         len,
      worm[[i1, 1]] -= dx;
      Do[worm[[i, 1]] -= dx, {i, 1, i1 - 1}];
      worm[[i2, 1]] -= dx/2;
      worm[[i2, 2]] = 
       Sqrt[len^2 - (worm[[i1, 1]] - worm[[i2, 1]])^2];
      Sow[worm]
      ]][[2, 1]]
   ];
contr[i0_, worm0_, dx0_] := 
  Module[{worm = worm0, dx = 1/10, i1 = i0, i2 = i0 + 1},
   If[EvenQ[i0] || i0 >= Length[worm], Print["i1 must be odd"]; 
    Return[]];
   Reap[
     While[(worm[[i2, 1]] - worm[[i1, 1]] - dx) >= dx0,
      Do[worm[[i, 1]] -= dx, {i, i2, Length[worm]}];
      worm[[i2, 1]] = worm[[i2, 1]] + dx/2;
      worm[[i2, 2]] = 
       Sqrt[len^2 - (worm[[i1, 1]] - worm[[i2, 1]])^2];
      Sow[worm]
      ]][[2, 1]]
   ];
move[worm0_, target_] := 
  Module[{worm = worm0, res = {worm0}, dx = 1/10, i1 = 1},
   While[worm[[1, 1]] - target >= dx ,
    i1 = 1;
    While[worm[[1, 1]] - target >= dx && i1 < Length[worm0],
     res = Join[res, ext[i1, worm, target]];
     worm = res[[-1]];
     i1 += 2;
     ] ;
    i1 -= 2;
    Do[res = Join[res, contr[i, worm, 1]];
     worm = res[[-1]];
     , {i, i1, 1, -2}];
    ];
   res];

worm0 = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, 0}};
target = -14;
dat = move[worm0, target];
ListAnimate[
 Graphics[{Green, Thick, Line[#]}, PlotRange -> {{target, 9}, {0, 2}},
     Axes -> True] & /@ dat]



Quick and dirty helped me get out of a rut. I am not the greatest at being able to not analyze too little or too much.

I am going to name him Lemay.
